# Would newspapers in 1890 London have printing presses in their offices?

Tags: united-kingdom, victorian, london, journalism

For a story I'm writing, taking place in London around 1889/1890, I'd like to know if the main newspapers, like the Daily Telegraph or the Daily Chronicles, who had their offices in Fleet Street, would have their printing presses in those same offices. If the answer is yes, does anyone know what they looked like ?

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, @Emilie! What has your research shown you so far?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the presses were in the offices in Fleet Street.

For a picture see wikipedia picture entitled "New_Daily_Telegraph_Offices_Fleet_Street_ILN_1882" from the Illustrated London News in 1882[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/New_Daily_Telegraph_Offices_Fleet_Street_ILN_1882.jpg]

Another article gives this as credit: HERITAGE-IMAGES/PRINT COLLECTOR
[image: Press room, offices of the Daily Telegraph, Fleet Street, London, 1882]

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was most useful !!!

Comment: Links to the wikipedia articles would make this a better answer.

Comment: @AllInOne The wikipedia article gave the history of the Daily Telegraph and did not really mention where the priniting was done - the picture is direct evidence

Comment: Depends on what is meant by "offices".  Using the usual US meaning of the word, they would not be in the offices, they would be in another part of the same building.  From what I've read, the presses of those days were quite noisy & messy, so putting them in the actual offices would be impractical.

Comment: I interpreted the question to mean "under the same roof".

Comment: I also understood under the same roof and the whole building is called the Daily Telegraph offices in the picture