# When did London newspapers start to use typewriters in their offices?

Tags: united-kingdom, victorian, london, journalism

I'm a French journalist writing a book, whose main character of is also a journalist working in the 1890's, but I lack some background.

I wonder when typewriters started to get used in British national newspapers? I know they were invented in the mid-century, and that after WWI journalists commonly used them, but was that the case in 1890? Would it be unlikely to find such an invention in The Daily Telegraph or the Daily News in that year?

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, @Emilie! What has your research shown you so far?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].
Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment given this question as well? See https://history.stackexchange.com/q/54486/25535

Comment: Not at all, I'm writing a book as I explained in the first draft of my question, but it was edited. I'm a french journalist myself and the main character of my story is also a journalist working in the 1890's, but I lack some background.

Comment: Looking at the edit history,  I understand why the previous editor (@sempaiscuba) made the changes he did, but it did cut away all of the context. Using your comment, I've put back some of it. I hope it's enough enough to explain the question's context a little better. Going forward, you'll find yourself regularly editing your posts so that they can stand by themselves, flow better, and also make it possible for people to answer them without a lot of duplication of effort.

Comment: @Spencer Last time I looked, I just corrected the grammar in the title.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Sorry, you're right; edit history can be hard to decipher on a phone. Everything's so tiny.

Comment: @Spencer Thanks for the edit, it's better with a brief context !

Comment: @sempaiscuba Thanks also for your edit, I'm sorry but english is not my mother tongue so even when I try to check my grammar, I make some mistakes

Comment: This is a surprisingly difficult question to answer. I like it.

Comment: Something else to consider is that typewriters may have been used by copy-typists rather than journalists, with the text dictated or otherwise communicated (as happened in other types of offices for writing correspondence etc).

Answer (score 2):

Judging by [Jenson (1988), *Using the typewriter: Secretaries, reporters and authors, 1880–1930*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0160791X8890036X) ([author's Twitter](https://twitter.com/jolijensen?lang=en)), and assuming similar developments on both sides of the Atlantic, the answer would be yes:

> The first claim, that the typewriter was deployed when it "made sense," is sup- ported by the rapidity with which the typewriter was adopted in American life in the 1880s, even though at least sixty writing machines of various sorts had been invented and patented since 1830. The first commercial machine was engineered in 1873; by the 1880s, a matter of a mere decade, Scientific Amen'can reported that over 40,000 machines were in regular use. Salesmen even claimed that the machine "sold itself" as a necessary business tool. During the same period, judges complained about the increasing wordiness of typewritten legal briefs, and would-be authors were advised that typewritten manuscripts were more readily saleable.I°

The author even has a section about the Newsroom specifically:

> #### Typewriters in the Newsroom
>
> Typewriters entered the newsroom without the fanfare and consternation that accompanied their arrival in the business office. One contemporary observer credits the advent of the linotype with forcing the widespread adoption of the typewriter. His claim is that typesetting was so much faster that printers required longer, more legible, less bulky "takes. ''18 He views the adoption of the typewriter as part of a more general (and natural) process of newsroom mechanization. [...]
>
> Copy produced via the typewriter was considered more legible and thus more appealing to editors, so outside contributors were urged to submit typewritten copy. In 1894, Shuman claims that "the outside contributor is almost compelled to have his article typewritten if he wants it to have the fullest chance of acceptance" in a newspaper. 2°
> Shuman also notes that "The machine is rapidly coming into general use in news- paper offices and the time has already come when the reporter who can manipu- late the typewriter has a decided advantage in securing a position. ''21

I didn't read the entire article, but it also includes discussions on the preoccupations of the time, such as how typewriters introduced more women in the workplace as secretaries. (The latter gets echoed in [this other article](https://www.branchcollective.org/?ps_articles=arlene-young-the-rise-of-the-victorian-working-lady-the-new-style-nurse-and-the-typewriter-1840-1900), which is about the UK more specifically.) Methinks it'll give you plenty of context for your book.

The linotype reference in the quote is almost certainly about the [Linotype machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linotype_machine).

Some of these [related scholarly articles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?client=safari&rls=en&uact=5&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&q=related:vBLTgmcDMsk7WM:scholar.google.com/) might also be useful in your research.

Comment: Are these long quotes from a book still under copyright meeting a "*fair usage*" constraint?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: axed.

Comment: +1 Nice find, even if it doesn't directly answer the question about London. I did a lot of googling on this and came up with nothing.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Thank you very much for you answer ! Indeed, it does not answer the question about London newspapers but will offer a lot of useful background ! The article about the women employed as secretaries is particularly interesting, as my main character is a woman ! Thanks again.